# About passing a pointer as parameter to a function: does it actually create a new pointer in the function?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
    void foo(int arr2[5], int* x2_ptr) {
         x2_ptr = &arr2[4];
         cout << *x2_ptr << endl;
         return;
    }

    int main() {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int x = 9;
        int* x_ptr = &x;
        foo(arr, x_ptr);
        cout << *x_ptr << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I thought this would print out `5` and `5`, but turns out it would print `5` and `9`. So, when the **pointer** `x_ptr` is passed to the **function** `foo()`, did it actually create a **NEW POINTER** called `x_ptr2`? I find this strange, because I thought the **pointer** `x_ptr` itself is passed and then any change to `x_ptr2` would change `x_ptr` too. What's the exact mechanism behind this?

Comment: Pointers are special variable type that contains memory of the value. In your code you are passing the pointer as value so x2_ptr is local to foo. If you modify x2_ptr you are only modifying its local variable. If you want the caller pointer to be modified pass it as a reference. 
i.e int*& x2_ptr)

Comment: "...did it actually create a NEW POINTER called x_ptr2?". Yes, it did create a new pointer called `x2_ptr`. `x2_ptr`, not `x_ptr2`.

Comment: Probably the biggest step towards understanding pointers is realizing that there is nothing special about pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the pointed data but the value of the pointer itself. To change the pointer you would do

```
*x2_ptr = arr2[4]
```

which would do what you thought. Assigning to the location pointed by `x2_ptr` the value at `arr2[4]`. `x2_ptr` is a variable local to the function which is storing a memory address.

You could either:

- change the value of `x2_ptr` to point to somewhere else
- change the value pointed by `x2_ptr`, so at address specified in the variable

If you still can't see it try to imagine how it works:

```
    x2_ptr
--------------
| 0x12345678 |  -----> 9
--------------
```

If you do `x2_ptr = &arr2[4]` you obtain

```
    x2_ptr
--------------
| 0xabcdef01 |  -----> 5
--------------
```

so you are changing the memory address stored in the variable to make it point somewhere else. The pointer is storing a different attress but no value is changed.

If you do `*x2_ptr = arr2[4]` instead you are effectively doing

```
    x2_ptr
--------------
| 0x12345678 |  -----> 5
--------------
```

so you are modifying the value at address 0x12345678, thus modifying the original one.

Comment: Thank you so much. But what I'm wondering here is that, when the function is called, there will be TWO pointers pointed to the address of (x = 9) which is x_ptr and x_ptr2, so any change in the link of x_ptr2 won't affect x_ptr, right? Do I understand it right? At first I thought it won't create x_ptr2; instead it will use x_ptr, so that's i'm wondering.

Comment: Yes, I totally got what you said. Thank you!

Comment: A short question: is there anyway that I can pass the pointer ITSELF to the function (meaning not create a copy of the pointer)?

Comment: You can pass the pointer to the pointer, eg `int** x_ptr_ptr = &x_ptr`. In this case you can dereference it and set the value of the original pointer, eg `*x_ptr_ptr = ..`. It's a game of boxes.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is copied, but both the original pointer and its copy refer to the same address. This way, when the copied pointer is dereferenced, the original value is got.

For example, if pointer A is located at address 1000, and it points to a value located at address 500, then its copy will be located at an address besides 1000 (the address of A), but still refer to a value located at address 500.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I finally got it! But a short question: is there anyway that I can pass the pointer ITSELF to the function (not create a copy of it)?

Comment: The closest way to pass the pointer "itself" (to use your words) is to pass a reference to it.   Instead of the second argument being `int* x2_ptr`, make it `int *& x2_ptr`.    Any assignments to `x2_ptr` in the function will then be visible to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out (excuse the pun): You have 2 different pointers initially pointing to the same location. This why if you change the int value *pointed-to* by either pointer, it reflects in both places; but changing *where* either pointer points to does not. *The pointer is copied, but the location **pointed-to** is not*.

Based on your other comments and questions I believe what you're looking for is the following:

```
//replace
void foo(int arr2[5], int* x2_ptr)
//with
void foo(int arr2[5], int*& x2_ptr)
```

I.e. you want a reference (`&`) parameter of type `int*`. Without the reference, you have a copy of the pointer, and your local change of the **pointer itself** doesn't affect the source. It's important to *not get confused* by the effect of changing the *pointed-to* value *after dereferencing* the pointer and thinking changing the *by-value* pointer variable might be the same.

Jack has a comment about using a pointer-to-pointer (i.e. `**`) which would also work if you implement it correctly. But reference-to-pointer `*&` is more explicit about your intent.

However, either way this is not the sort of thing you should do very often. You're basically adding a level of indirection to access the "real" value of interest, *the `int`*. So I'm wondering if you're trying to solve an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a  copy of  a  variable to  a  function  you  pass the  address of  the variable allowing the   code of your function to access it using the dereference opearator.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. It's what OP is doing already: `int* x_ptr = &x;` pointer set to the address of the `x` variable. `foo(..., x_ptr);` is therefore _passing the address of the variable_